# jQuery function for change css bg color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make a function that change css property of an object.
I tried code below

```
function setBgColor($obj, $color) {
    $obj.css("background-color", $color);
}
setBgColor($(".bg-red"), "red");
```

and it works.
but I would like to to make the function to be called from an object like this

```
function setBgColor($color) {
    $(this).css("background-color", $color);
}
$(".bg-red").setBgColor("red");
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use jquery prototype to do this:

```
$.fn.setBgColor = function($color) {
    return $(this).css("background-color", $color);
}
$(".bg-red").setBgColor("red");
```

Comment: @user4448631 you should click "correct" for this answer. ;)

Comment: it says i must wait for another 4 minutes

Comment: I think that, within jQuery prototype, you do not need `$(this)`, but just `this`. Also, this could be made more similar to other jQuery function, by doing `$.fn.bgcolor = function(color) { return (typeof color == 'undefined') ? this.css('background-color') : this.css('background-color', color); }`